# Programmatically querying MSDN?

Tags: .net, msdn

Is there a way to query MSDN.com programmatically? Essentially I have a class name, namespace or other identifier and want to find the MSDN Documentation page, ideally passing in a version as well (.net 3.5, .net 4.0, Silverlight etc.)

I think I saw some API, but googling for "programatically query MSDN" wasn't very helpful, seems like MSDN is a bad term to google for...

Answer (score 7):

MSDN provides a public service to publish documentation content:
http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx

Example usage can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163541.aspx).

Comment: [Package This!](http://packagethis.codeplex.com) uses this service to create a CHM file from selected online content.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at some MSDN documentations. Looks like it is using this template:
`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/<Fully_Qualified_Name>(v=VS_Version).aspx`
[For example for HttpContext on .Net 4.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
VS Versions:

- .Net 1.1:  (v=VS.71)
- .Net 2.1:  (v=VS.80)
- .Net 3.0:  (v=VS.85)
- .Net 3.5:  (v=VS.90)
- .Net 4.0:  (v=VS.100)

Comment: I think that last line should be 4.0

Comment: @Henk: Yep! just noticed that. Thanks for noticing though.